# What are the best words to convey the same meaning of scab and dead skin, respectively?

Tags: word-choice

I aggressively cleaned my ear canal with my finger and the canal got scratched. After several weeks elapsed, it got naturally healed but I cannot hear clearly probably because of the dead skin or scab abandoned inside. I want to remove it in an ear-nose-throat clinic and to explain it to the doctor.

I am afraid if I make use of a wrong word and makes the doctor confused. I have tried to use a free online dictionary, I got the following results.

- dead skin : 壊死した皮膚
- scab : かさぶた

What are the best words to convey the same meaning of scab and dead skin, respectively?

Comment: I'd suggest "きずあと"。I think the image is that you had a "きず" in your ear. Then, the "あと" is a vague term that kind of means something produced by your "きず" that shouldn't be there. Surely, confirm that with a native speaker. btw: you offered TMI in your question...

Comment: @natlang: What is TMI?

Comment: "TMI" is just im slang: "too much information". the question was just a little graphic is all.

Comment: @natlang: Because I just copied from my question in [another site](http://health.stackexchange.com/q/1349/668).

Comment: Probably I will say as follows: たぶん、私の耳の中に、吹き出物があって、爆発して、リカバリーして、壊死した皮膚があるだろうと思います。

Comment: @FriendlyGhost 'Explode' in this sense can't be translated as 爆発.

Comment: [壊死](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%E5%A3%8A%E6%AD%BB&tbm=isch) is [necrosis](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=necrosis&tbm=isch) (Be careful, there are a lot of horrifying images in the links). It's far more serious than you thought.

Comment: As simple as 死んだ皮膚 will suffice in this situation, I think. FWIW the technical term for this is 落屑【らくせつ】/desquamation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already got the best word for "scab".

The word I would suggest for "dead skin" is 「[角質]{かくしつ}」.  「[壊死]{えし}した[皮膚]{ひふ}」 sounds more like a dictionary definition.  It is not something a patient would say.

That said, you could just copy the following and show it to your doctor.

「数週間前、耳掃除をやりすぎてしまい、耳の中を傷つけてしまいました。一応、傷自体は治っていると思いますが、かさぶたや角質が詰まっているせいか、聞こえが悪いような気がします。今日は、耳の中を掃除していただければと思って参りました。」